# html5 pattern special characters not working from function

Tags: php, regex, html, function, validation

Let´s see if I can explain clearly, as it´s not an easy topic:
I´m using a HTML5 pattern validation inside a form to allow special characters like vocals with quotes and ñ. This is the pattern I´m using: 
[A-Za-zñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0-9 .,-/_:)(]+
If I set the validation inside the own php page it works properly:

[...]

```
<form method="post" action="mod_netrep.php">
<?php 
$tcoments="<input type='text' pattern='[A-Za-zñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0-9 .,-/_:)(]+' title='SOLO ALFANUMERICOS y  .,-/_:)(' maxlength='100' style='width:250px;font-weight:bold;' name='coments' id='coments'>";
echo $tcoments;
?>
</form>
```

[...]

But when I call the validation to a function included in another php, it doesn´t validate any quoted vocal or ñ (ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ) but the other special characters, numbers and regular ones still work:

[...]

```
<form method="post" action="mod_netrep.php">
<?php 
$tcoments=tmenu("coments");
echo $tcoments;
?>
</form>
```

[...]
This is the function tmenu():

```
function tmenu($dato){
$tmenu="<input type='text' pattern='[A-Za-zñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0-9 .,-/_:)(]+' title='SOLO ALFANUMERICOS y  .,-/_:)(' maxlength='100' style='width:250px;font-weight:bold;' name='$dato' id='$dato'>";
return $tmenu;
}
```

Please let me know if something is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sound like you could be in the wrong character encoding somewhere. Are both PHP files UTF-8?

Comment: Ok thank you very much delboy1978uk, it seems that was the issue, stupid me. I´ve just set the external php (which was un-encoded) as UTF-8 and now it´s working. Please post the answer so I can mark it as right solution and thanks again!

Comment: thanks, added! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably in a different character encoding.

As a general rule of thumb, you should ensure everything is UTF-8!

That means, your IDE, PHP files, Database, HTML meta tag, everything!

If you need to convert strings from another encoding, see this! http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php